# How to change the store sort in store locator

Tags: magento

Has anyone know how to change the (sort)order of stores displayed as a result in a unirgy store-locator? 
By default it gives the results w.r.t. to shortest distance from the given location. 
We have a change the sort order.
Is there any way to change this default behavior or it is managed through Map-JS?

Comment: what do you want to sort with ?

Comment: We have a field as 'no_of_styles' associated with each store,we need to sort in the descending order of 'no_of_styles'.
For example: if store A is having 200 styles and store B is having 300 then, store B should come first and then store A.

Answer (score 0):

You should really refer to the documentation first, or contacting the extension developers before requesting help from the community.

According to their documentation, there is an option to set the Sort Order in the configuration page:

http://unirgy.com/wiki/storelocator/main-config

Go to `System > Configuration > uStoreLocator` and look for `Results Sorted By`.  Change to the method of sorting you require.

Comment: in my version of extension, this setting is not included.
Anyways I have found the solution while loading the collection.